# Deploy p2 repo to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, p2

I have created my own p2 repository using some plug-ins. Hence, I have below folder structure locally generated using maven:

```
repository
   |- plugins
       |- myplugin1.jar
       |- myplugin2.jar
   |- features (empty)
   |- artifact.jar
   |- content.jar
```

I am facing problem to deploy this to nexus. I would like to use this URL in eclipse target platform as a site.
Please help me by pointing out steps to upload p2 repository to nexus.

I tried mvn clean deploy command but it did not helped because it did not deployed it as p2 repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1) Don't deploy your repository to nexus, copy and unzip it into a webserver instead. This is the classic way, since you have your repository exactly the way you want it.

2) Install the [Nexus Unzip Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin) which provides an uploaded repository using a special "unzip" URL.

As an alternative, you could install the nexus-p2-repository-plugin which basically turns your whole repository into a p2 repository.

Answer (score -1):

You can also combine the org.sonatype.plugins:maven-upload-plugin and the Nexus [nexus-unpack-plugin](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-) to upload and explode your update site zip from Nexus.

1. Install the appropriate `nexus-unpack-plugin` from [repository.sonatype.org](http://repository.sonatype.org): simply download the `bundle.zip` and extract to `sonatype-work/nexus/plugin-repository`.  Restart Nexus.
2. Add the `Unpack` role to your deployment account.
3. Create a Maven Site in Nexus to host your update site; these are essentially file areas.
4. Configure your build to use the `org.sonatype.plugins:maven-upload-plugin`. The [m2e project](https://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.site/pom.xml) serves as a nice example.

Assuming you used the m2e site pom.xml as a skeleton, then you'd invoke maven like:

```
mvn -Ppublish-site-latest \
    -Dmy.site-serverSettingsId=my-server-setting \
    -Dmy.site-compressed=http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/my-site/content.compressed \
    install
```

to upload your zip to Nexus to the nexus-unpack-plugin, which will explode it into the configured location.  Note that the `my.site-compressed` property uses `repositories` rather than `site` as the nexus-unpack-plugin matches only `service/local/repositories` (a bug?), but it works fine for sites.

If you get FORBIDDEN or UNAUTHORIZED errors, then you don't have the Unpack permission set up correctly.